# How to escape parenthesis in Perl Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, text

If I have a string such as:

```
 JOURNAL   Yeast 10 (11), 1503-1509 (1994)
```

How do I get the two numbers in the parenthesis( 11 and 1994) ? One way I attempted was using:

```
/\s+JOURNAL\s+.*\((\d+).*\((\d+))/
```

but this doesn't work. So my two questions:

1. How to escape the parenthesis so I can use match them in the RE ?
2. How to get the above two numbers ?

I am doing this in Perl. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
\((\d+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oW5zL3/1)

**Explanation:**
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

Answer (score 6):

Your regex was fine, except that you had an extra `)` on the end.

```
$_ = " JOURNAL   Yeast 10 (11), 1503-1509 (1994)";
if ( /\s+JOURNAL\s+.*\((\d+).*\((\d+)/ ) {
     print "one: $1, two: $2\n";
}
```

If you want to explicitly make sure there is an ending parenthesis after the digits, then:

```
/\s+JOURNAL\s+.*\((\d+)\).*\((\d+)\)/
```

Answer (score -1):

Also consider using the octal equivalents for characters, it can be easier to read sometimes.
So to find (11) the regex would be: \050(d+)\051

Comment: Sorry, I don't find this easier to read at all... I can quickly see that `\(` escapes the brace, but I'll have to look for an ascii table to find out what character `\050` is. Octal codes are just noise here.

Comment: As a 'one off' I agree with you its not easier to read but if you have many complex regex compares with special characters you become familiar with the octal values and from experience I found it can be less error prone to use the octal equiv's, as always YMMV. The point of my post is to let ppl know there is this option. --Ross

Comment: @Ross how do you make an error typing `\(` compared to some code that you clearly will get wrong unless you write them everyday which you don't?

Comment: @Sahsahae the answer to your question is you may get '\\(' wrong 
when the regex search contains many parenthesis, my post is to 
point out that there is another way to write a regex, giving 
the user the option. I'm not suggesting that using octal codes 
is the way to go for all character searches.